# Can this dispatch_once singleton ever return nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Trying to find an issue we are experiencing intermittently, that seems to be occurring on devices with low memory conditions. The suspected cause is the NSDateFormatter singleton being nil.

Is there any possible situation where the singleton pattern below could return nil?

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatterUTC {

    static NSDateFormatter *formatter;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.dateFormat=@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ";
    });

    return formatter;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know no, I singleton will stay for the lifetime, but a date formatter can return a nil date if it can't parse the date format correctly

Comment: Generally speaking I would say no, but there isn't any strongly enforced guarantee that alloc will return non-nil so, ya know, it's *possible*... But in practice no.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not doing something weird then no.

There are two cases how this could return nil:

1. The alloc or init methods return nil when instanciating the date formatter.  This could happen if there is no more heap memory available. But in this case your program most likely will crash anyways. Most Objective-C code (probably including Apples frameworks) is written under the assumption that heap memory cannot run out.
2. Someone overwrote the static pointer with nil but leaving the onceToken in place. This is pretty unlikely to happen by accident, but not impossible. A memory corruption bug like this probably would also break other things and make the app crash.

So for all practical purposes you can assume that your function will always return a valid object. If you really wanted to make sure you could also add an assert before your return.